# jQuery JSON is not parsing

Tags: jquery, json

This is my code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var json = JSON.parse($.getJSON('file.json')); 
    $( '#tform' ).append( '&lt;div class="name"&gt;'+json[1].Language+'&lt;/div&gt;' );
});
```

According to the jQuery doc `$.parseJSON()` is deprecated in v3. So I'm using `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON.

**file.json:**

```
[
    {"Language":"jQuery","ID":"1"},
    {"Language":"C#","ID":"2"}
]
```

But there is nothing printing in my html.

Comment: Why are you using HTML entities like `&lt`? Do you have something in your console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JSON in a callback, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('file.json', function(json) {
    $( '#tform' ).append( '<div class="name">'+json[1].Language+'</div>');
  }); 
});
```

It only appends the `Language` to the HTML element after it successfully requested `file.json`. [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/xuyami/edit?js,output) with a fake api.

Comment: Nothing happened and console is empty :(

Comment: Could you do `console.log(json)` just before the append? What does it say?

Comment: it's saying [Object Object]

Comment: So that's an empty object? Or does it have any contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

store the json which you read from file into a variable, then parse those data using **JSON.parse**

```
var inputData = '[{"Language":"jQuery","ID":"1"},{"Language":"C#","ID":"2"}]'; 
var json = JSON.parse(inputData);
console.log(json[0].Language);

$('#tform').append('<div class="name">' + json[1].Language + '</div>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/213wu7w8/